# Request for critique of proof

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I have started working through the Berkeley Problems in Mathematics for fun and it would help to have some input on solutions I come up with that are different from those included in the book (especially since I've just started working with this text for the first time).  One problem requests that I prove that $\cos^p(\theta)\le\cos(p\theta)$ for $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$ and $0<p<1$.

For my solution, I let $\theta$ be fixed, thus for all $p$, if not $\cos^p(\theta)\le\cos( p\theta)$ then we have $\cos^p(\theta)>\cos(p\theta)$.  If we let $\theta=0$, then we have $1>1^{(1/p)}$, that is, $1>1$.  This is clearly a contradiction and thus the original inequality holds.

Comment: The negation of "for all $p$, $x\le y$" is "for *some* $p$, $x>y$".

Comment: All you prove here is that $\cos^p\theta \le \cos(p\theta)$ when $\theta = 0$, i.e. $1 \le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof is incomplete. One way to look at this is that you imply that $\theta$ can be anything but then suddenly you only bother to prove the $\theta=0$ case. Another way is to say that if you want to set up a contradiction, then you need to use the negation suggested by Karl Kronenfeld - the negation of "all sheep are white" is "there's a sheep which isn't white", not "sheep number 1 isn't white". Just proving sheep number 1 is white is not a contradiction to there being *some* not-white sheep.